.NET Identity /login not returning tokens
Note: this is my first time using .NET identity and I am flying by the seat of my pants.
I am building a project with .NET identity. I defined my endpoints with  Relatively early in the project I had Identity working, returning bearer tokens, and successfully authenticating and accessing secured endpoints with Swagger.
At some point the /login endpoint stopped returning tokens, instead just returning an OK status. So i started debugging. When I step through the /login endpoint in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.IdentityApiEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapIdentityApi<>() I noticed that /login doesn't actually return any data. There is just a comment that reads: The signInManager already produced the needed response in the form of a cookie or bearer token. This makes no sense to me whatsoever, but clearly, it works because I had this working at some point. I assume there is something in my configuration that is messing up signInManager's ability to return data, however, it does that.
I've tried stepping through signInManager as it tries to sign in the user but there are thousands of lines of code and many branches the code could take. I don't know where to start. I've looked through my configuration settings, but I don't really know what half of this stuff does. I've compared my settings to what other people have done, but everyone seems to do this differently, so I can't tell what's standard, what's this guy's weird design choices, and what's irrelevant.
Here is a copy of my builder method so you can see my configuration https://pastebin.com/2z3Y5Vbj
Whats wrong? why doesn't /login return tokens?

Are you calling the login endpoint with useCookies and useSessionCookies set to false?

@daandsp not sure what you mean... I call the login endpoint using Swagger's Try it Out button I don't ever set 'useCookies' or 'UseSessionCookies' in that process. And i don't set ether of those values in my code.

The /login endpoint from the .MapIdentityApi<>() supports parameters to set whether or not you want to set cookies instead of a bearer in return. It should be visible in Swagger.

"The signInManager already produced the needed response in the form of a cookie or bearer token." SignInManager writes tokens directly to the HttpContext response. It's weird but that's how it works.

Noted. That is indeed strange. If i felt up to it i would change that for my version but I've touched /login enough already

I think the problem is about the scheme name. When using "asp.net core identity" with endpoints. It will have two working modes when login.
Mode 1 is gererating cookie for scheme CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme (also called "cookies").
Mode 2 is reponsed with bear token for the scheme IdentityConstants.BearerScheme (also called "Identity.Bearer").
As you said, there have been so many ways to use asp.net core identity, but there are some differences.

AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>() : you have to manually AddCookie() and AddBearer(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme)
AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>() : It contains AddCookie()
AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>() : It contains AddCookie()
AddIdentityApiEndpoints : it contains AddCookie() and AddBearer(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme)

So After checking your code, you messed with the cookie scheme with the jwt scheme name which shouldn't work properly.

(sry for the late response, sick and brain dead) when you said I was messing with the cookie scheme with the jwt scheme name, do you mean AddAuthentication(...).AddCookie("Identity.Bearer",... ?

Also when you say that one of your methods contains another method, does that mean that running the first method also runs the 2nd?

I've tinkered around. Tried removing the AddCookie part but I get an error System.InvalidOperationException: No sign-in authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Identity.Bearer'. The registered sign-in schemes are: Identity.Application, Identity.External, Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe, Identity.TwoFactorUserId. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookie("Identity.Bearer",...)?

yet another thing. I can't AddCookie() or AddBearer() to AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>() or the options within it. I assume I am misunderstanding how these methods work...

@hutonahill Such as AddIdentity already contains  addcookie(), you will only need to AddAuthentication().AddBearer(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme). By the way ,Identity.Bearer is a jwt scheme not cookie scheme.

It Worked! Thanks!

@hutonahill Glad to hear that. Would help to follow the instruction https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)
